# problemas al ejecutar un shell script , problemas en el "if"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, script, shell-script

hola verán fui a correr un shell script en la terminal pero me sale un error como si no pudiera aceptar la condición en el primer (ya le di los permisos) el ejercicio dice lo siguiente:

Construya un Shell Script llamado lartc.sh que permita recibir los siguientes
parametros y sean validados:

lartc –i ethN –r clase 1 porcentaje 1 ... clase n porcentaje n

lartc -i ethN –cln

lartc -i ethN -voip bw

EthN: un número del 0 al 9 para colocar con la palabra eth ej. “eth2”

Clase: un número binario de 8 bits ej. “01100101”

Porcentaje: un numero de porcentaje ej. “20%” (Entre 0 - 100)

Bw: un numero decimal (Positivo o Negativo)

**ejemplos:**

lartc -i eth0 -r 01101010 39% 01001010 51% 01111010 20%

lartc -i eth6 -voip -2000

lartc –i eth3 –r 00000011 50% 11001100 69%

lartc -i eth9 –cln

y les dejare un screen shot de lo que me sale en consola
[image: que yo sepa en sheel script = o == es lo mismo pero no se que pasa]

**el $1 es lartc y dice lartc= lartc lo cual es cierto pero no ejecuta lo demás y no se porque**
**aqui esta el codigo**

```
#!/bin/bash
numero='^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$'
cod='^[01]{8}$'
proc='0*(100|[0-9]{1,2})%$'
if [$1="lartc"] && [$2="-i"]; then 
   if [$3="eth0"] || [$3="eth1"] || [$3="eth2"] || [$3="eth3"] || [$3="eth4"] || [$3="eth5"] || [$3="eth6"] || [$3="eth7"] || [$3="eth8"] || [$3="eth9"]; then
  if [$4="-cln"]; then
 if [ -z $5 ]; then 
             echo correcto
else 
                                        echo incorrecto
fi
elif [$4="-voip"]; then
 if [$5=~ $numero]; then
                echo incorrecto
else
                    if [ -z $6 ]; then
                       echo correcto
 else 
                       echo incorrecto
fi
fi
elif [$4="-r"]; then
                      if [ $5 -le 0 ]; then
                         echo incorrecto
else 

 for ((num =6; num <=$5+5; num=num+1)) do
cont=0
cont=$num+1
if [${!num}= ~$cod] && [${!cont}= ~$proc]; then 
echo incorrecto
else 
echo correcto
fi
done
fi
else 
echo incorrecto
fi
else 
echo incorrecto
fi
else 
echo incorrecto!
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios errores en el código. pero me centraré en el que causa el mensaje de error:

```
./lartc.sh: línea 5: [=lartc]: orden no encontrada
```

La construcción del tipo `[ ... ]` *no* es sintaxis especial de la shell. Es en realidad una variante del comando [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) que tiene la particularidad de requerir obligatoriamente que su último argumento sea `]`. Y como cualquier otro comando, es necesario que el nombre del comando y sus argumentos estén separados por al menos un espacio en blanco o tabulación.

Es decir, **en vez de `[foo=bar]`, lo correcto sería escribir `[ foo = bar ]` o `test foo = bar`**.

Por otro lado, el error en el primer comando `[ ... ]` hace que la primera condición del primer bloque `if` falle, por lo que se ejecuta el comando `echo` que se encuentra hasta el fondo del código. Es por ello que el resto del código no es ejecutado.

Tu bloque `if` es realmente masivo ([¡6 niveles de anidación!](https://gist.github.com/nxnev/678911603b9bfccef04b7db38ac61063)), pero esta es una simplificación de lo que sucede:

```
if false; then
  # Aquí van el resto de if anidados
else
  echo incorrecto
fi
```

En cuanto al resto de errores, solo daré consejos generales:

- Entrecomilla las expansiones de parámetro (ejemplo: `"$var"` en vez de `$var`) para prevenir efectos indeseados del [*field splitting*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05).
- Combinas sintaxis de [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) y [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). Decídete por una.
- Haz más robusto el manejo de argumentos. Podrías usar [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html).